# How to create an online PHP editor?

Tags: php, editor

So I would like to create a php editor for the browser, I need it because sometimes I make little test codes what makes my computer messy and I always need to delete or manage those files too and I also would like to split the browser into two frames, the first for PHP the second for the page what is edited so I could see the result, and debug it faster.

But I don't really know how should I make it because PHP needs to be executed, it's not enable to save it like HTML.

Comment: `opendir()`, `readdir()`, `closedir()`, `fopen()`, `fwrite()`, `fclose()`... the most important functions to reach what you want to have. The editor itself is just to show a file within the dir ... The execution itself can be done via `cURL` or via visiting the file in your browser. Where's the problem? :)

Comment: the problem is that I want to write the code in the browse, but thanks for the functions what you listed, let me check them :)

Comment: Start Here: http://www.google.com/search?q=online+php+editor

Comment: @shamittomar link will show you PHPanywhere. An application to allow you to code online.

Comment: @Glycerine, and that's exactly what OP wants to achieve through his app. Why re-invent the wheel? :)

Comment: I tried PHPanywhere, but doesn't works... Asks me to create a parent folder when I want to create my first folder to create files, when I don't have any folder!?

Comment: I use phpfiddle.org for self testing but if you ask for online editor for your website, I recommend https://github.com/nerkn/onlineeditor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is for your own, internal use only, you can always [`eval`](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) the code received via POST - you just need to pass the code as a string to the function. But don't even think about exposing the service for the world, as by default it opens the possibility for malicious user to do almost everything on the server.

Comment: This would have to be locked down to hell, but yes.  Or it could save a document and include it.

Comment: @Orbling If it's just for his internal use there is no need for locking anything. One of my teachers also recommended doing this for quickly testing our code (not that I use this to test my code)

Comment: @AntonioCS Internal need not stay internal, I meant ensure it is restricted to localhost or the LAN at the least.

Comment: eval is evil. It should be avoided at all costs. In this case there are options.

Comment: @Glycerine Please don't say that. There are many php applications that use eval. Many drupal modules for example use this, like cck. Eval has is uses. You just have to be careful not to run code given by a third party.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever i need to test a snippet of code i just use either the same test.php file in my user dir (Because thats where CMD starts so i dont have to navigate directories etc):

```
win+r (run) > notepad test.php, save.

win+r > cmd > php test.php
```

OR just use the -r parameter on the PHP cli interface:

```
***C:\Users\myuser>php -r*** `for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){ echo ':-)'; }`
```

:-)

Answer (score -1):

I would use javascript AJAX to send your code using POST to a php page which writes the file. This can happen every few key strokes or when you press a save button.
Then when the php file has been saved just make a callback function which starts second AJAX call to a php file which will include the file you have saved just a second ago. It will echo that back to a callback javascript function which will replace a div on the right side of the page you are on with the result. This could also be 2 separate pages. You could make the result come up as a popup that stays open if you want. This would be the basics to make this work.